# How to release file lock with Camel when not consuming from seda queue?

Tags: java, apache-camel

using Apache Camel, I have a route that take a file, elaborate it through a bean and send it to a seda queue.
If nobody is consuming from that queue, the lock on the file remains.
Is there any possibility to release the lock in this situation?
I just tried "discardIfNoConsumers=true" as seda option but doesn't works.

I'll show to you my route:

```
from(loadInputUri())
            .split()
            .tokenize(getLineSeparator(), getBatchSize())
            .streaming()
            .stopOnException()
            .bean(Bean.class)
            .end()
            .to("seda:outQueue?discardIfNoConsumers=true");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ah well spotted about the `discardIfNoConsumers=true` as that is indeed a little bug in Camel as the completion is handed over to a new copy of the message which then is just dropped. So the completion is never triggered to delete the marker file.

I logged a ticket about this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9700